# Learning OSGi : ExtendedLogService & ExtendedLogReaderService

Tags: logging, osgi

I'm trying to learn OSGi for my project, and came across the `ExtendedLogService` and `ExtendedLogReaderService` which was introduced in Equinox 3.5. Is there any tutorial or example available that would help me to understand how it works and to use it on my project?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet tried the ExtendedLogService. When looking into the interfaces it looks similar to popular logging frameworks. So the big question is why not just use an established logging API? Using the OSGi logging service will tie all your code to OSGi. The established frameworks work inside and outside OSGi.
I can recommand to use slf4j in your application. To make this work in OSGi you need the [pax logging framework](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging). Pax logging also supports the other big logging APIs like log4j and java.util.logging. If you are doing a server project then you might also want to take a look at [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) which  already includes pax logging and a lot of other libs.

Comment: Thanx, I'll look through it...
Is there any tutorial , work-through example in the net that I can follow through?

Comment: You can take a look at my Tutorials about Apache Karaf. http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials . I do not handle the logging explicitly but it is integrated in some examples. Basically you just use the slf4j API like outside OSGi and do not do any logging configs in the bundle. The logging config is done in a config file of Karaf: etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg . Basically this is just a log4j config.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not implement the ExtendedLogService, But i do implemented the `org.osgi.service.log.LogReaderService` `org.osgi.service.log.LogEntry , org.osgi.service.log.LogListener` which i think helpful.

About tutorial i follow this one [Logger Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/osgi-logging/wiki/UnderstandingTheOSGiLogging)

My view towards the logging feature in OSGi,

Structure of logging in OSGi

I had specifically avoid log4j and slf4j because they don't work on S0A architecture.
although there is PaxLogging available which makes log4j is to work on OSGi fied environment,but i think the information of bundles into the log4j property will violets the design pattern. There are many developers who questioned the log4j in OSGified env.

```
                                  LogListener (LogListnerImpl)
                                                ^
                                                |       
                                                | Dispatches the LogEvent to LogListner
                                                |
 Log Service ---- Send a LogEvent -->   LogReaderService (log.jar)  
    ^
    |
    |
Bundle write a log
```

===========================================================================

I will appreciate if experienced developers correct me.